# What is the "healthy" way to handle deletion of pointers to objects from a list?

Tags: c++, list, pointers

Let's say we have a `Buyer` class.

`Buyer` has an `email` data member and a `getEmail()` member function.

Also we have a method like the one below that deletes a pointer to `Buyer` objects from a list of pointers to `Buyer` objects

```
void removeBuyer(Buyer* b){

    list<Buyer*> :: iterator z;
    for(z = buyersList.begin(); z != buyersList.end(); ){//buyersList is the list of pointers to Buyer objects
        if( (*z)->getEmail() == b->getEmail() ){
            z = buyersList.erase(z); 
        }
        else
            ++z;
}
```

Then let's say I try to "log in" with the `Buyer` object whose pointer I just deleted.

```
void logIn{
    cout<<"Give email"<<endl;
    std::string e;
    std::cin>>e;
    list <Buyer*> :: iterator it;
    for(it = buyersList().begin(); it != buyersList().end(); ++it){
        if (e == (*it)->getEmail() ){// This is where the crash eventually occurs
            //something
        }
    }
}
```

This sometimes works fine, others a crash occurs with the `0xC0000005` return.

I know that the `buyersList` (inside `logIn`) is updated and holds all the pointers minus the deleted one. And when I dereference the iterator `it`, `it` then "becomes" one of the elements of the list, hence a pointer that exists and is not deleted.

I know that I'm probably doing something wrong with the handling of the pointer I just deleted.
What am I missing exactly?

Comment: To remove an element from a standard container, I suggest you use [`std::remove` or `std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) instead of your own loop. And to fix the crash you have, please read about [the erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase–remove_idiom).

Comment: Is `buyersList()` return by reference? if it returns bu value, you have issue.

Comment: @Jarod42 that was the issue, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that `buyersList()` returned by value and not by reference.